# Generate a list with a for-loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

A human has 22 chromosomes and 2 sex chromosomes X and Y.

I would like to generate these chromosome name from 'chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3' ... 'chr22', 'chrX' and to 'chrY' with input of only number of chromosome and X and Y.

```
# Input the data here
number_of_chr = 22,'X','Y'

for x in range(number_of_chr[0]):
    print('chr'+str(x+1))
```

From the code I can generate 'chr1' to 'chr22', but how can I generate 'chrX' and chrY' and append them into a list, so that the end result is like this:

```
chrID  = ['chr1','chr2','chr3',......'chr19','chr20','chr21','chr22','chrX','chrY']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> number_of_chr = 22,'X','Y'
>>> n, *rest = number_of_chr
>>> ['chr%s'%i for i in chain(range(1, n+1), rest)]
['chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3', 'chr4', 'chr5', 'chr6', 'chr7', 'chr8', 'chr9', 'chr10', 'chr11', 'chr12', 'chr13', 'chr14', 'chr15', 'chr16', 'chr17', 'chr18', 'chr19', 'chr20', 'chr21', 'chr22', 'chrX', 'chrY']
```

Comment: This is what I wanted because of the inputs. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

```
chrID = [ 'chr{}'.format(x) for x in list(range(1,23)) + ['X', 'Y'] ]
```

Comment: This simple code is really good! but I needed to get the input values first. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `append` to append to a list

```
r = list(range(1,23))
r.append('X')
r.append('Y')
l = []

for x in r:
    l.append('chr'+str(x))
```

`range` returns a list of numbers(in python2.7) in the range.Just append x and y to that list.
I guess you are using python 3, so you will have to convert the range to a list as shown above.

Comment: Thanks @rjv. Yes I'm using pyhon 3 but it gets `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`. If i print 'l' it has only 'chr1' to 'chr22' no X and Y. If I run the code should the x being X and Y are being added by 1?

Comment: yeah,thats because you are adding 'X' with 1.I have fixed it